# Problem with XML(ATOM) from SAP using XSL to Display Multiple Attributes(within same element) in a HTML table

Tags: xml, xslt, sap-basis

Hi I am very new to XML.

I am trying to transform XML to HTML using XSL.  Internet Explorer keeps giving a blank display.
The XML has been generated by a SAP demonstration system I have built for practice.
The result I am expecting is a HTML table that will hold the 6 or so attributes of each element in a row.

**XML below:**

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="ZSFLIGHT_PROJECT_SRV" xml:lang="en" sap:schema-version="1">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xml_from_sap.xsl"?>



<EntityType  Name="Carrier" sap:content-version="1">

<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Carrid"/>
</Key>

<Property Name="Mandt" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Client" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Carrid" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Airline" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Carrname" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Airline" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Currcode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="5" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Airline Currency" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" sap:semantics="currency-code"/>
<Property Name="Url" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="255" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="URL" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
</EntityType>


<EntityContainer Name="ZSFLIGHT_PROJECT_SRV_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
<EntitySet Name="CarrierSet" EntityType="ZSFLIGHT_PROJECT_SRV.Carrier" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:addressable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
<EntitySet Name="Carriers" EntityType="ZSFLIGHT_PROJECT_SRV.Carrier" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:addressable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
</EntityContainer>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" href="http://vhcalnplci:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSFLIGHT_PROJECT_SRV/$metadata"/>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="latest-version" href="http://vhcalnplci:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSFLIGHT_PROJECT_SRV/$metadata"/>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

**XSL Below:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
   xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match = "/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>SAP Flights</h2>
            <table border = "1">
               <tr bgcolor = "#9acd32">
                  <th>Sytem Name</th>
                  <th>Carrier ID</th>
                  <th>Carrier Name</th>
                  <th>Currency Code</th>
                  <th>URL</th>
               </tr>

               <xsl:for-each select = "EntityType/Property"> 
                  <tr>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Name"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Type"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Nullable"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@MaxLength"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Name"/></td>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm also going to close this as a duplicate. You've fallen into a trap that hundreds of people fall into (you can find them by searching for "XSLT default namespace"). Closing as a duplicate isn't a criticism, because there's no way you could have known about all these other questions without first knowing the answer, but marking it as a duplicate helps declutter the space when other people do searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take into account the namespace of the elements in your XML file.
Here's how you could do this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
   xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
   xmlns:edm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm"
   exclude-result-prefixes="edm edmx">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match = "/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>SAP Flights</h2>
            <table border = "1">
               <tr bgcolor = "#9acd32">
                  <th>Sytem Name</th>
                  <th>Carrier ID</th>
                  <th>Carrier Name</th>
                  <th>Currency Code</th>
                  <th>URL</th>
               </tr>

               <xsl:for-each select = "edmx:Edmx/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/edm:EntityType/edm:Property">
                   <tr><td>Here</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Name"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Type"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Nullable"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@MaxLength"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select = "@Name"/></td>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknt4

As to why you were not seeing any output, how are you running your XSLT transformation?